# Is there any way to set localisation settings in Google Now?

Tags: localization, google-now

Is there a way to set localisation settings for Google Now?

Specifically, I want to change the fact that if I tap on the score of a football game, Google Now searches for "soccer" instead of football. Since the only country in the world that calls football "soccer" is America, that search returns mostly American results, which are quite useless to me.

My address on my Google account is in the UK, my language is set to British English and my phone is localised to the UK. I suspect that Google Now results are already localised to an extent and that they overlooked this particular issue.

Comment: "Since the only country in the world that calls football "soccer" is America"  ahh, I'm not sure that's true!

Comment: "Since the only country in the world that calls football "soccer" is America"  Ahh, I'm not sure that's true.   In ireland "football" means gaelic-football, while the other round-ball sport is called "soccer".  In New Zealand, football is short for rugby-football, and scooer is, well, soccer!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the location settings for Google Now are managed from a mobile app not from a web application.